# Basic Circuit Question: what is the meaning of the area (integral) under the v(t) = curve?

Tags: voltage

This is a basic circuit question. What is the meaning of the area under the voltage curve (integral) v(t) = w/q, w = joules, and q = charge? And what is the units?

AL

Comment: Do the dimensions match on both sides of your equation?

Comment: v(t) = dw/dq where dw is Joules, and dq is Coulombs.

Comment: Why is this question is closed? Really? What other details or clarity does this question need? I searched this forum for answer and couldn't find one, and that is why I posted the question.

Comment: Where does this question come from, what prompted this question? Voltage is not usually measured in terms of work per charge. In any case, the integral of voltage with respect to time, is flux. Which isn't usually of importance unless you're working with magnets. This also sounds more like a physics or education or tutoring question, than an electronics design question.

Comment: A circuit question would need a circuit.

Answer (score 3):

No, it indicates the definite integral of \$v(t)\$ over the interval the graph covers.

And if you connected that to a fixed resistance \$R\$ it still does not indicate energy because instantaneous power is \$v^2(t)/R\$.

With a fixed resistor it would tell you the coulombs of charge that passed through the resistor though, since \$i(t) = v(t)/R\$ it would be the area divided by \$R\$.

As far as charge, think of the charge flow at any given instant being the current (coulombs per second). So if the current is 1 A and it flows for 1 second, we have one coulomb of charge. If your graph is 1 second long then the area under the \$i(t)\$ curve (which is a straight line) is the charge. And the area under the \$v(t)\$ curve looks the same, just multiplied by the load resistance \$R\$.

Analogous to calculating the total distance you've moved by integrating your speed over some period of time (or looking at the area under the speed curve over a certain period of time)

Now if \$i(t)\$ or \$v(t)\$ is not constant, but varies over time then we can still use the area under the curve because it's a linear function. Mathematically, the area under the \$i(t)\$ curve is the charge \$Q\$:

$$Q = \int_{t=0}^{T_0}i(t)dt = \frac 1 R \int_{t=0}^{T_0}v(t)dt$$

Comment: Perhaps it may help your last line teach a little more if you'd show how *time* is involved. The units of \$\int V_t\,\text{d}t\$ is Webers (volt-seconds.) This divided by Ohms is, of course, Coulombs. Or, put completely another way while still the same thing, it's the average current times the integration period. A person named "always learning" is perhaps champing at the bit for this little extra.

Comment: Got it! FYI, I am trying to figure out what the relationships, and meanings of all the basic electricity equations, and their derivatives, and integrals are. It's not straightforward to me! So, it would be nice if someone provided them here, or posted a link where they could be found. Thanks.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning That's probably a separate question of its own.